# Adding mutliple events to the same function causes maximum stack size to be exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allow a user who is using an editable table to both submit changes through pressing the enter key as well as focusing out on the element. The keypress works fine. However, the focusout is causing maximum stack size to be exceeded.I have tried event.stopPropagation() to stop the continuous event but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is what I have:

```
$(document).on('keypress focusout', '.prefill1', function(event) 
{
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13' || event.type == 'focusout')
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($(this).attr('edit_type') == 'button')
        {
            return false; 
        }

        //get the original entry
        var original_entry = $(this).attr('original_entry');

        var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('row_id'); 

        var row_div = $(this)               
        .removeClass('bg-warning') //add bg css
        .css('padding','')

        var col_name = row_div.attr('col_name'); 
        var col_val = row_div.html(); 

        var arr = {};
        //get the col name and value
        arr[col_name] = col_val; 
        //get row id value
        arr['row_id'] = row_id;

        if(original_entry != col_val)
        { 
            $(this).blur();
            var name = col_val;
            var finder = $(this).closest('tr');
            var col_val2 = col_val.toUpperCase();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "page.php",
                success:  success,
                 dataType: "json",
                data: { row_id: row_id, }
               })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                }); 
            function success(data) {
            useData(data, name, finder);
            var flen = data.length;
            console.log(flen);
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: I see nothing related to `click` in the posted code...

Comment: I meant focusout. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check to see if the event type is `'focusout'` before you call `blur()`.  That might be causing another `focusout` event.

```
/** ... **/
if(original_entry != col_val) { 

  if(event.type != 'focusout')
    $(this).blur();
  }
  /** ... **/
```

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!